# Create an XML element with namespace in XMLDocument

Tags: xml, vb.net, xml-namespaces, xmldocument, system.xml

I'm working with the XMLDocument class in VB.net.
I want to get element with name "a:Product", but following code:

```
dim doc as new XMLDocument 
dim pr as XMLElement = doc.CreateElement("a:product")
pr.InnerText = "123"
doc.AppendChild(pr)
```

return element in XML without "a:":

```
<product>123</product>
```

Where do I go wrong?

Comment: I updated your title to better fit the described problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
dim pr as XMLElement = doc.CreateElement("a:product", namespaceURI);
```

Where `namespaceURI` is the namespace represented by the alias "a". This is usually something like "http://schema.example.com/blahblah". Just look it up in your XML file.